# Python TCP Server - Remove Connection

Tags: python, server

I made a server using python and  TCP. I want to know when to disconnect a client from the server, how this is done?. I'm thinking of doing the following:

1. Create a task on the client that sends a data every second or every two seconds, these data report the server that the client is active.
2. Create a task in the sever to update the "time out" of all the connections, if "time out" of connection is more than 6 seconds, then the connection is lost and then the client is disconnected from the server ...

would be something like this on the server side:

```
#dictionary whose key customer and value "time out" accumulated
timeOut = {}

# for each client that is active ...
for client in activeConnections:
     #if has accumulated more than 6 seconds without receiving report from the customer 
     if timeOut[client] >= 6:
        remove connection of client from the server

        inform other users that the client is disconnected...
```

Is this fine? Is There a better and efficient way to do this? 6 seconds is a good measure for the "time out"?

Comment: How are you managing multiple tcp connections? Are you multiplexing them yourself or does each connection run in its own thread?

Comment: The server handles "threads", a separate process for each client, active connections are stored in a list (activeConnections), the server may disconnect every customer when necessary, the question is when.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would try to do it...

Each client connection consists of:

1. a socket handle (gotten from the `accept` call)
2. a Queue - call this the "logic queue"
3. a thread I'll call the "socket thread"
4. another thread I'll call the "logic thread"

The relationships are:

- the socket thread only reads from the socket handle; it will only put messages onto the queue
- the logic thread only writes to the socket handle; it only reads messages from the queue
- the socket thread will put the following kinds of messages onto the queue:

  - the following input was received from the client
  - the client timed out or the client closed the connection
- the logic thread reads messages from the queue and processes them; the possible messages it can receive on the queue are:

  1. client closed connection / client timed out
  2. received some input from client
  3. another client connected / disconnected

There will be a couple of other threads and queues, too:

- a thread to perform the accept() and create new connections - the accept thread
- a thread to broadcast messages to the other logic threads
- a queue for the broadcast thread to read from and for others to write to when they want to broadcast a message
- all threads will have to have access to the broadcast queue.
- only the broadcast thread reads from the broadcast queue; the accept threads and all of the logic threads can write to the broadcast queue
- the broadcast thread will need to know about all of the queues for the logic threads

Here is a scenario of what happens when a client times out:

1. Client times out
2. the socket thread for that client puts a "client timed out" message onto its queue
3. the logic thread gets the message, closes the socket, kills the socket thread, and puts a message onto the main server thread's input queue
4. main server thread gets the message and broadcasts it to all of the other queues for the other clients
5. the logic thread for each client gets the client disconnect message and emits the notification over its socket

Another scenario... when a new client connection is created we:

1. the accept thread detects a new connection
2. the accept thread creates a new socket thread, logic thread and queue
3. the accept thread enqueues a "new connection" message onto the broadcast queue
4. the broadcast thread sees the new connection message and broadcasts it to the other logic queues
5. each logic thread gets the message and sends some notification out the socket

Any questions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your explanation is very complete. 6 seconds is a good measure for the "time out"?

Comment: That's for you to decide. I would say most server applications allow TCP connections to remain open indefinitely. Btw, if you found the answer helpful, how about at least up-voting the answer if not accepting it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no reputation enough to vote, I'm new.
Thank you!